# PHP, CallBack function

Tags: php, function, callback

I am studying PHP and i am trying to understand about callback functions, I really looked around at the manual, At stackoverflow and more websites, And i really dont understand what is **PHP CallBack Function** , If can some one can please help me understand about this functions, I am looking for simple **explanation/guide** thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Do you have read this page? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand? What part is unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Wikipedia - Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_science))

> In computer programming, a callback is a reference to a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code. This allows a lower-level software layer to call a subroutine (or function) defined in a higher-level layer.

It's a function what you pass to your method or some other function, so it can be called later during that method - function execution.

For example you have callback `beforeSave` and you want do some logic before saving data to database file etc.. (in one place - DRY). You add logic into `beforeSave` callback and this callback being called before data saved.

Same is with function on manual for example `array_filter($input, callback)` it requires that you pass some function to be executed with $input data.

For ex. pass anonymous function:

```
array_filter($input, function($var) {
   // returns whether the input integer is odd
   return($var & 1)
});
```

Will return to you all odd array values, you can change logic in anonymous function to what you want, but `array_filter` internal mechanic will be always the same (iterator algo)

Comment: Thank you for you answer Aurimas Ličkus, have a nice day.